# how to set viewport color

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am working on opengl in android. Can some-one let me know how to set the background color for viewport(instead of the entire screen). I have 2 viewport in my application and I would like to set different color for the 2 viewports.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `glClear` affects the whole framebuffer and not only the current viewport (not sure about that), then you might also use the scissor test:

```
glScissor(x, y, w, h);
glEnable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
glClearColor(r, g, b, a);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

I'm pretty sure the scissor test influences `glClear`.

Comment: Hi, thanks. The glScissor does work. B/w, earlier I did try scissor test but was getting compilation error. A simple change in glEnable does the trick. Used glEnable(gl10.GL_SCISSOR_TEST) instead of glEnable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST)

Comment: @Raj If it helped, up-voting (and maybe accepting) would be appreciated. And regarding the `gl10.`, of course you need to adapt the code snippet to your specific GL bindings, I just used raw OpenGL C code, but the idea is the same.

Answer (score 1):

For each viewport do:

```
glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); // adapt this to the color you want
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

Before drawing in it.

Comment: Hi, Sorry should have said this. I have already tried these calls. But the calls affect the entire screen rather than the viewport. Do correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes, glViewport doesn't influence glClear, You need to use additional clipping or a scissor test before clearing. Alternatively you can draw the viewport backgrounds using quads in orthogonal mode with z-buffer writing off.